# Correct crystal oscillator simulation

Tags: oscillator, crystal

I want to simulate a crystal oscillator with an 8 kHz frequency which is adjustable. When I simulate this circuit below, the frequency responder gives me an exact 8 kHz frequency and the oscillator indicates a sine wave.

Every time when the crystal triggers the transistor, the sine wave will flow through it. Does this mean the crystal, which produces a sine wave too, triggers the 2N2222 transistor properly and has a higher sampling rate than the sine wave input (10 V, 1 hz)? That means the input could be a microphone and the output could be an antenna.

[image]

[image]

Please correct me if I'm wrong.

I researched many times in internet for a working example oscillator for proteus simulation. Every time when i found one example and tried it out in proteus preparing the circuit, it did not work. I have one question about this issue. Is proteus simulation reliable enough to make frequency measurements with crystals?

The one circuit oscillator below should work, but i does not. What is the problem with that? I can't get a frequency output.

[image]

I have just tested another oscillator. Proteus says 1 GHz frequency. When I play around with the inductor, the frequency changes that way. I am sure there is a method to make inductors with small values. The question is about the stable frequency which has been generated. Is there maybe a crystal variant of this oscillator? The circuit is below:

[image]

Comment: Where did you get this oscillator topology? it's certainly not one I've seen before.

Comment: First, thanks for feedback. I have constructed this circuit just now in proteus. The question is about if this circuit is realizable in real world. I have the components here waiting for being soldered together.

Comment: @dude, I would like to help but---you need to study, or search internet for training on oscilattors in general and crystal oscillators in particular. There is alot out there. Question needs details for clarity.

Comment: @dude I would be extremely surprised if this worked in reality. I'm already very surprised it works in simulation.

Comment: That would be a non-working circuit. You can realize it with physical components and it would still not work. It only shows a frequency response, because you feed in an external frequency sweep measurement signal and measure the output, which obviously shows that your circuit passes energy at 8 kHz. Also, if you try to buy an 8 kHz crystal, you likely can't find any with such low frequency.

Comment: One of the features of crystal oscillators is that they produce a very stable frequency determined by the charicteristics of the crystal, so you can't have a crystal oscillator with an adjustable frequency.

Comment: @PeterBennett Actually you can, that's why you can buy voltage controlled crystal oscillators, so VCXOs do exist. They are tunable to maybe few tens of PPM. Also programmable crystal oscillators do exist, but they have a PLL.

Comment: @Justme:  I thought about mentioning trimming the crystal, but didn't want to confuse the OP.

Comment: What is the maximum frequency of the oscillator in proteus simulator? If i can get the answer here, then any problem will not be that what it might be.

Comment: I think it is on RAM memory depended. 1-100 Mhz oscillator simulation should not require that much memory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a radio transmitter circuit i have found in internet.
I tested it in proteus and i have seen that the crystal oscillator works fine. I suppose most of the people have the irritating in the art of the oscillation what makes us expect a pure frequency whatever is written on the crystal. The problem is that when something is being oscillated, the result does not have to be between plus and minus in that frequency that is given on crystal. Whatever the input is, that will be oscillated. Maybe the output is about 8 Kilohertz what the proteus responder says while oscillating, but it is being oscillated in a higher frequency. The output says this, because of the input is that between plus and minus voltage, so the output is the same.

[image]

[image]

[image]